# MailCore SMTP Invalid Server Certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, smtp, mailcore

I have an issue with MailCore2 (iOS) connection to **smtp.live.com** SMTP server.
There where not problems connecting to **pop3.live.com**, **smtp.gmail.com** or **smtp.mail.yahoo.com**.

Here are the settings

```
[_sessionSMTP setHostname:@"smtp.live.com"];
[_sessionSMTP setUsername:@"mytestmail@outlook.com"];
[_sessionSMTP setPassword:@"MyTestPassword1"];
[_sessionSMTP setPort:587];
[_sessionSMTP setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS];
[_sessionSMTP setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeSASLPlain];
[_sessionSMTP setUseHeloIPEnabled:YES];

MCOSMTPOperation *op = [_sessionSMTP checkAccountOperationWithFrom:
                       [MCOAddress addressWithMailbox:@"mytestmail@outlook.com"]];
    [op start:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
    }];
```

I constantly get:

```
Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=4 "The certificate for this server is invalid."
```

Are there any special requirements for Live mail ? I know MailCore can use Live's SMTP server since Sparrow is doing this.

Kind Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

try setting `checkCertificateEnabled` to NO:
    [_sessionSMTP checkCertificateEnabled:NO];

From the MailCore docs:

> checkCertificateEnabled
>
> When set to YES, the connection will fail if the certificate is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use openssl to connect to smtp.live.com:587, proceed with SMTP, issue STARTTLS, and view the certificate chain: `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.live.com:587`  The certificate chain looks fine to me: .  It looks like the certificate that they are using is signed by GlobalSign.  I'm wondering if there is a setting that needs to be made in MailCore to specify that GlobalSign is a trusted CA.